# How do I filter using the external Odoo API?

Tags: python, odoo

My code is as such

```
    search_domain = [
    '&',
    ('product_id', '=', 'Product_x'),
    '&',
    ('lot_id', '=', 'AG:04/10/2023:UID520:6666'),

    ('on_hand', '=', True),
]

# Use the search domain to find the specific location
lookuplocationbasedonname = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.quant', 'search_read', [search_domain])
pprint(lookuplocationbasedonname)
```

The search returns a stock.quant record that has the following.

```
  'on_hand': False,
```

I have tried multiple ways of filtering, the Odoo docs don't make the filtering clear.

Comment: Use Domain like this ['&', '&', ('product_id', '=', 'Product_x'), ('lot_id', '=', 'AG:04/10/2023:UID520:6666'), ('on_hand', '=', True)]

Comment: It still returns info such as.   'on_hand': False. I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo sets the `search` attribute on the [on_hand](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L94) field and will use the search function when the field is used in the search domain (the field search function will be called before the model search function).

Odoo will [use all quants](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L160-L170):

```
def _search_on_hand(self, operator, value):
    """Handle the "on_hand" filter, indirectly calling `_get_domain_locations`."""
    if operator not in ['=', '!='] or not isinstance(value, bool):
        raise UserError(_('Operation not supported'))
    domain_loc = self.env['product.product']._get_domain_locations()[0]
    quant_query = self.env['stock.quant']._search(domain_loc)
    if (operator == '!=' and value is True) or (operator == '=' and value is False):
        domain_operator = 'not in'
    else:
        domain_operator = 'in'
    return [('id', domain_operator, quant_query)]
```

The `_get_domain_locations` function will return all stock locations when no parameters are given

Odoo returns `'on_hand': False` because the field is not stored

Comment: THANK YOU ! This was driving me up a wall. Had no idea about the on hand field.

Answer (score 1):

The proper data type for the domain argument should be like this.

```
search_domain = [[
    ('product_id', '=', 'Product_x'),
    ('lot_id', '=', 'AG:04/10/2023:UID520:6666'),
    ('on_hand', '=', True),
]]
```

Comment: The data returned is still with on_hand being false